Dependent names in C++ template
I have templated class that includes two nested class like below
#include <iostream>

template<typename A>
class c
{
    class a
    {
        protected:
        int i = 0;
    };
    class b: public a
    {
        public:
        void print()
        {
            std::cout << "i of a: " << i; // fails
            //std::cout << "i of a: " << this->i; // works
        }
    };
};

This gives compliation error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'. I would expect the failure to relate to class a being dependent on the template parameter, but it does not seem to be the case here since a is not dependent on A.
I tried reading about dependent names in templates, but I am still unsure why this error occurs. Could someone explain the theoretical reason for this behavior?
Surprisingly this compiles without issues on MSVC but not in GCC and Clang. Any insights on why GCC/Clang behave differently from MSVC here would be greatly appreciated!

Sidenote: You can add using a::i; to b if you'd like to use i without this-> in b.

The code compiles with clang 19.1.0 too.

@MKR It doesn't for me - even if I remove -pedantic.

@MKR It doesn't for me: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x5nevWzKM

Sorry, I had removed template temporarily to check and forgot to put it back. It did not compile with template


since a is not dependent on A

It is. You can specialize a.
#include <iostream>

template<typename A>
class c
{
  public:
    class a
    {
      protected:
        int i = 0;
    };

    class b: public a
    {
      public:
        void print()
        {
            std::cout << "i of a: " << this->i;
        }
    };
};

template <>
class c<int>::a
{
    // No `i`!
};

int main()
{
    c<int>::b x;
    x.print();
}

<source>:18:46: error: no member named 'i' in 'c<int>::b'
   18 |             std::cout << "i of a: " << this->i; // works
      |                                        ~~~~  ^


Surprisingly this compiles without issues on MSVC

You didn't enable the standard conformance mode. All modern compilers will accept some invalid C++ by default.
It starts rejecting your code with /std:c++latest or with /permissive-.

thanks. However in this case no  specialization has been declared. I wonder what prevents the compiler to determine that i of class a is available to the class b?

@Ashiful The error happens during the initial parse of b, not when it's instantiated, so the compiler can't see the lack of specializations at that point. This now isn't specific to your case, it's the same story as every other case where you need this-> in a template. Hard to say why exactly they did this, probably to be able to quickly reject misspelled global variables/functions even without the instantiation.
